# Single-line text not truncating as expected in float layout

Tags: html, css, css-float, ellipsis

I have a basic HTML structure with a parent `div` and two children: `span` and `a`. The `a` is floated right, and I want the `span` to grow with the size of its text content until it hits the floated `a`, at which point I want the text to truncate with ellipses.

Here's a link to a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/56ua0jc8/

```css
.parent {
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  border: solid 1px green;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.link {
  border: solid 1px red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="text">Some text that is so long that it's pushing the link down instead of truncating. What I really want is for the text to truncate with ellipses instead.</span>
  <a class="link" href="someUrl">Link</a>
</div>
```

Currently the `span` is expanding and pushing down the floated `a` without truncating the text. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to drop float and enter flexbox world:

```css
.parent {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex; /*declare flexfox*/
}

.text {
  border: solid 1px green;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.link {
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin-left: auto; /*push it to the right*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="text">Some text that is so long that it's pushing the link down instead of truncating. What I really want is for the text to truncate with ellipses instead.</span>
  <a class="link" href="someUrl">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. I definitely need to catch up on flexbox. Thanks for the fast answer!